R function to write a spark dataframe into a SQL table
I heve this code in a databricks notebook
%r
library(SparkR)
spark <- sparkR.session()
df <- sql(long_query)
write.df(df, path = new_table, source = "delta", mode = "overwrite")

that runs without raising any error, but it seems that it doesn't create the table.
What should be the correct way to create new_table with the data form df?
-- UPDATE --
Solved using
%r
library(SparkR)
spark <- sparkR.session()
sql(create_statemnt_for_new_tableusing_long_query)

